# Android Collapsing Toolbar not using inertia like Google Play App does

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm using the Android Design Support Library to create an Activity with a Collapsible Toolbar with a nice fading effect, just like Google Play or Whatsapp's Contact profile. I will put the activity layout at the end but bear in mind this is just the default Collapsible Activity layout to which I added an ImageView to the AppBarLayout to create the Toolbar <-> Image fade effect.

My problem with this implementation presents itself as 2 symptoms I will describe:

- The activity content is long, when I want to scroll up quickly with a fast swipe the scroll will stop before expanding the Toolbar. I want it to continue, when I'm at the bottom of my NestedScrollView and I do a quick finger swipe to go all the way to the top of my activity I want this scroll to go and expand the Toolbar, this is the way the Google Play app behaves or Whatsapp's profile does.
- Similarly when the Toolbar is expanded there is no inertia to the scroll, a quick swipe down will scroll a tiny bit, again this is not how Google Play or Whatsapp profile behaves. Once the Toolbar is collapsed the scroll behaves as it always has in ScrollViews, ListViews, etc. A quick swipe will allow you to go the bottom or top (unless there is a lot of content).

Is the behaviour I describe supported by the Design Support Library?

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height_custom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/cuthbert"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:minHeight="100dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_scrolling.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: So now when you scroll down, the scrolling stopps(lags) on the moment when the toolbar is fully hidden and you need another move to keep scrolling (same happens when you scroll up)?

Comment: When I scroll up the behaviour is as you describe. Scrolling down is different, because swipe is not possible with the Toolbar Expanded, the moment you stop touching the screen, it stops scrolling. Creating a new Scrolling Activity in Android Studio using the provided template will give you exactly this behaviour I'm describing.

Comment: Found any workaround. Is this issue reported??

Comment: I did not find a solution. Not sure why it should be reported as it seems to be the 'correct' behaviour, just not a nice one.

Comment: Have you still found a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines in :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
   app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
   app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
   app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update support libraries to 26.0.0 ( especially design support library ). They finally fixed this issue after years of complaining.